# kinect object measuring

Tags: camera, kinect

I am currently trying to figure out a way to calcute the size of a given object with kinect

since I have the following data

angular field of view of the lens
distance
and width in pixels from a 800*600 resolution

I believe this can be possible to calculate. Does anyone has math skills to give me a little help?

Comment: Are you trying to get the square footage of the cross section of the object of interest, linear dimensions, or attempt to recover volume?

Comment: linear dimensions for now... maybe later I will try volumes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some [trigonometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometry), it should be possible to approximate.

If you draw a [right trangle ABC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aTrigonometryTriangle.svg), with the camera at one of the legs (A), and the object at the far end (edge BC), where the right angle is (C), then the height of the object is going to be the height of leg BC. the distance to the pixel might be the distance of leg AC or AB.  The Kinect sensor specifications are going to regulate that.  If you get distance to the center of a pixel, then it will be AC. if you have distances to pixel corners then the distance will be AB.

With A representing the angle at the camera that the pixel takes up, d is the distance of the hypotenuse of a right angle and y is the distance of the far leg (edge BC):

`sin(A) = y / d`

`y = d sin(A)`

y is the length of the pixel projected into the object plane. You calculate it by multiplying the sin of the angel by the distance to the object.

Here I confess I do not know the API of the kinect, and what level of detail it provides.  You say you have the angle of the field of vision.  You might assume each pixel of your 800x600 pixel grid takes up an equal angle of your camera's field of vision.  If you do, then you can break up that field of vision into equal pieces to measure the linear size of your object in each pixel.

You also mentioned that you have the distance to the object.  I was assuming that you have a distance map for each pixel of the 800x600 grid.  If this is incorrect, some calculations can be done to approximate a distance grid for the pixels involving the object of interest if you make some assumptions about the object being measured.

Comment: I think that I didn't understood :(

Comment: Could you detail a little bit... I believe it's a language matter :P

y is the lenght of the pixel projected into the object plane??

Comment: I guess I got it...ok let's imagine that I have the kinect fixed on a support over a table, pointing down at a fixed height and I'd like to measure the boxes over the table!

I will need no pitagoras theorem for it... so I just need the second part you explained about the angular field of view right

Comment: and the final comment how should I pass it from pixels to metric values :S

Comment: @Killercode, I made an edit, hopefully it is more clear.  The units of measurements resulting (the y value) will be in the same unit of measurement you get from your kinect.